# Al hacer subconsultas en MySQL, al reemplazar el id en el where, se sigue mostrando la información de otro id

Tags: mysql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en MySQL:

**Tabla cursos**
[image: Tabla cursos]

**Tabla solicitudes**
[image: Tabla solicitudes]

Quiero mostrar los datos de curso accediendo a esa tabla a través del `idcurso` que está en la tabla `solicitudes`; lo estoy haciendo con la siguiente línea:

```
select * from cursos where idcurso = 1 
in (select idcurso from solicitudes where idcurso = 1);
```

Efectivamente me muestra la información del curso con `idcurso 1`.
El problema es que cuando cambio `idcurso = 1` por `idcurso = 2`me hace la consulta pero me sigue mostrando la información del curso con `idcurso 1,` no sé a que se deba este problema.

Comment: Que información te regresa y que información deseas obtener. Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que regresa ahorita y uno de lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: Cambie la condición en la cláusula `WHERE` de: `... where idcurso = 1 in (select...` a `... where idcurso in (select...`.

Comment: ¿Por qué colocaste `where idcurso = 1 in`?

Comment: Si quieres los cursos con id=1 basta con esto: `select * from cursos where idcurso = 1;` y si quieres los cursos con id=2 basta con esto: `select * from cursos where idcurso = 2;` y si quieres los cursos con id=1 o id=2 basta con esto: `select * from cursos where idcurso in (1,2);` no veo qué sentido tiene aquí usar una subconsulta a la tabla `solicitudes` como criterio ¿? Si quieres datos de `solicitudes` sí tendría sentido usar esa tabla, pero haciendo un `JOIN`.

Comment: Suena a [`INNER JOIN`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentencia_JOIN_en_SQL#Combinaci%C3%B3n_interna_\(INNER_JOIN\)).

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres los cursos con id=1 basta con esto:

```
select * from cursos where idcurso = 1;
```

Y si quieres los cursos con id=2 basta con esto:

```
select * from cursos where idcurso = 2;
```

Y si quieres los cursos con id=1 o id=2 basta con esto:

```
select * from cursos where idcurso in (1,2);
```

No veo qué sentido tiene aquí usar una subconsulta a la tabla `solicitudes` como criterio ¿?

Si quieres datos tanto de `cursos` como de `solicitudes` sí tendría sentido usar esa tabla, pero haciendo un `JOIN`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    c.idCurso, -- Pones el alias de cada tabla, punto y columna
    c.Nombre,
    c.Precio,
    s.idsolicitud,
    s.nombreAlumno
FROM cursos AS c 
    INNER JOIN solicitudes AS s ON c.idCurso=s.idcurso
WHERE c.idCurso=1  -- Si quieres 1,2 pon esto WHERE c.idCurso IN (1,2)
```

Al unir las tablas mediante `JOIN` podrás usar cualquiera de sus columnas tanto en el `SELECT` como en el criterio `WHERE`, o en el `ORDER BY` o en el `GROUP BY` ... etc, **usando siempre el alias de la tabla respectiva, un punto, y el nombre de la columna en esa tabla**.